# Circular Dependency when calling destructors

Tags: .net, dependencies, c++-cli, destructor, circular-dependency

I have the following architecture, and because of the inheritance, it is causing circular dependency when `destructors` are being called on the classes.

```
namespace IntOp
{
    ref class PwItem;
    ref class PwTag;

public ref class PwItem
{
    public:
      PwItem(void* arg1, <sometype>arg2, unsigned __int64 arg3);
      {
          // some constructor work
      }
      virtual ~PwItem(){};
      static PwItem^ PwItem::CreateItem(void* arg1, <sometype>arg2, unsigned __int64 arg3) 
     {
        if(arg2 is of type PTag)
        {  //  PTag = gcnew PwTag(arg1, arg2, arg3);
           //  return PTag;
         return gcnew PwTag(arg1, arg2, arg3);
        }
        else if(arg2 is of type PFile)
        {    //PFile = gcnew PwTag(arg1, arg2, arg3);
            // return PFile;
         return gcnew PwFile(arg1, arg2, arg3);
        }
        return gcnew PwItem(arg1, arg2, arg3);
     }

   private : 

     //PwTag^ PTag;
   //  PwFile^ PFile;  //Another type with PwItem as Base constructor
 }


public ref class PwTag : PwItem
{
    public:
    PwTag(void* arg1, <sometype>arg2, unsigned __int64 arg3) : PwItem (void* arg1, <sometype>arg2, unsigned __int64 arg3) {};
   virtual ~PwTag();
}}
```

So here, when I want to call a delete on `PwItem`, so it releases the instantiation of `PwItem`, then because of the inheritance, `PwTag` calls the `destructor` on `PwItem`, and the whole thing keeps repeating itself.

How can this issue be resolved? The `destructor` really needs to be called to release some stuff which is there in the class object.

**EDIT : Added calling code**

```
myServer srv = new myServer();
srv.connect();
while(true)
{
    PwItem ^item = srv.GetItem(<some string>); //This will invoke the GetItem function, which will call createItem()
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
}
```

**Actual GetItem() function**

```
PwItem^ myServer::GetItem(<some string>)
{

    // do some work, nothing new being instantiated etc. just arguments 1, 2 and 3, which do not cause leaks
    return gcnew PwItem::CreateItem(arg1, arg2, arg3);
   // Tried instantiating a PwItem pi; return pi.CreateItem(arg1, arg2, arg3); as well. No luck
   // Bypassed PwItem entirely, and based on arg2, called return gcnew PwTag(arg1, arg2, arg3); as well, no luck
   // Tried PwItem pi, ^tempPwItem; tempPwItem = pi.CreateItem(arg1, arg2, arg3); return tempPwItem; No luck
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to create a factory. But a rather unusual factory. You said your base class creates child class instances based on the type of object requested. But your code is doing something else.
Do you always have 1 instance per child class? Also, for each child class, will you keep its object in the base class (PwItem)? 
Also, no where it is mentioned in the CreateItem method, which child instance you require!
Let's say a PwXYZ child class comes along, then what will your code be? 
One of the mistakes I have seen is that you are sending a NON static instance of PwTag in a static function.

All you need in the base class is a STATIC CreateInstance method, that would take the type of object requested and returns the object. No need to keep any child class object in the base class.

```
 //You can have an ENUM >>> enum ItemType { PwTag,... so on};
  static PwItem* PwItem::CreateItem(ItemType type){
  //check which type of object is requested and simply return the instance      
}
```

Also, your base class should have a VIRTUAL(public) destructor. Since you are sending Base reference for a child class, it will result in memory leak if your try to delete it (deleting child object with base's reference), because child's destructor won't be called.

So, now your base class would just be

```
...

 public:
  PwItem();
  virtual ~PwItem(){};
  static PwItem^ PwItem::CreateItem(ItemType type) 
 {
    //switch cases OR IFs whatever you like...
    //return instance of the object requested
 }
...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The design is something which I've inherited and is causing a leak. The idea is, that someone asks for a `PwItem` object, using the `CreateObject` and in that function, it is determined that it is a `PwTag` which is being sought, and so a new `PwTag` object is created and returned.Basically, the base class is being used to instantiate objects of derived classes and they are being returned in that fashion. Unfortunately,assuming that something like `CreateItem` is being called in a `while` loop, it is causing leaks in memory. Any way to change this without majorly overhauling this architecture?

Comment: I've added some code to make it a bit clear. I did not actually have the child class object in the base, it was simply `return gcnew <child class>`, but because of the leaks, I wanted to explicitly call a `delete` on the `pointer` of the child class, which is why I used an object of the child class inside the base. They ( child and base ) kept on calling each other's destructors in turn.

Comment: Didn't work. Still leaks memory predictably at 8 kb per refresh.

Comment: If I keep the `PwItem()` constructor private, then how will the child class, in this case, `PwTag`, access it in its own constructor? `PwTag(void* arg1, <sometype>arg2, unsigned __int64 arg3) : PwItem (void* arg1, <sometype>arg2, unsigned __int64 arg3) {};`.

Comment: Yes my point exactly, as you aren't doing anything with the PwItem class, and are you sending the arguments to it... Now I imagine you wish to add some common functionality in PwItem. Logs are the only thing left now.

Comment: There is some. If the `ObjectType` does not match any of the defined ones in `CreateItem()`, it should return a `gcnew PwItem(arg1, arg2, arg3)`. But I cannot imagine where, if I put `createItem(arg1, arg2, arg3)` in a loop, is memory going to leak. All concerned classes are managed types, there is nothing I'm instantiating with `new`...`CreateItem()` simply calls returns a new instance of `PwTag`, and `PwTag` has only methods, no object declarations..

Comment: Do you have the references of all the instances you are creating? I remember you mentioning that there is a WHILE Loop or something that is creating? are you sure that it is keeping the references of all of the instances? (in an array or vector or something) Plus may I see the code you are using to delete?

Comment: Yes, it appears that you are keeping just one PwItem reference. I suggest, you create a vector of PwItems >>> std::vector<PwItem*> items = new vector<PwItems*>(); >>> then your while loop would be >>> PwItem ^item = items->push_back(srv.GetItem(<some string>)); 
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
>>> This will allow you to keep all the references, then you simply iterator over the vector and delete them one by one.

Comment: Ah, the calling code isn't designed for that. It is meant to keep checking for the value of, let's say, a `PwTag`, which might be getting updated from some other place, and whose value I deference using the `PwItem` object in the calling code. So this loop would need to run continuously for quite some time, and there's no place I know where I should Delete it explicitly. I just wished to know, where in the calling code, is there a leak...